# Pandas Rolling window - find date or number of actual days for min/max window

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a time series that look like this

```
                    open          high           low         close
date
1982-10-06   191.98   191.98   191.98   191.98    191.98
1982-10-07   195.59   195.59   195.59   195.59    195.59
1982-10-08   198.89   198.89   198.89   198.89    198.89
...
```

```
I find them minimum value over that time series for window = 20.  That low can happen on any of the previous 19 days.  id like to add to the dataframe either the date or number of days back that that low occurred. Can anyone help with this?

df['window_low'] =  df['low'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=20, center=False).min()
df['low_date'] = ?
df['number_of_days_back'] = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `idxmin`

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
id = df['low'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=20, center=False).apply(lambda x: x.idxmin())
df['low_date'] = df['date'].reindex(id).values
df['number_of_days_back'] = df['date'] - df['low_date']
```

Comment: thank you. can you explain what this is doing for my knowledge?  is it basically returning the index (in this case date) of the occurrences?

Comment: there is one issue w/ this in that there may gaps in the dates.  so would have to count the 'rows' between those two dates